# How to install Gerix-Wifi-Cracker?

Tags: software-installation

I've tried to install Gerix-Wifi-Cracker on Ubuntu 13.10, but it was unsuccessful. Does anyone know how to install it?

Comment: OP I have answered your other question about pyqt3 install.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm late with my answer but here it is just in case:

you can install the following packages and retry.

using this command line

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev qt4-designer
```

Answer (score 1):

First run this in your terminal to ensure you have all dependencies in place:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev qt4-designer
```

or `sudo apt-get install qt3*`

Then run these commands:

```
cd /home
wget http://www.clshack.it/nopaste/gerix-wifi-cracker-ng-2.0-bt7.deb
```

Then this one:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev # Installs tools to rebuild the debian package
mkdir /tmp/deb$$
cp /home/gerix-wifi-cracker-ng-2.0-bt7.deb /tmp/deb$$
dpkg-deb -x gerix-wifi-cracker-ng-2.0-bt7.deb deb # Extracts filesystem data
cd deb
dpkg-deb -e ../gerix-wifi-cracker-ng-2.0-bt7.deb # Extracts metadata
```

Then download this file [svn.sh](http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=AvtFVRuK), put it in /tmp/deb(random numbers, probably 4 of them) and rename it to **svn.sh**

Lastly run this code in the terminal:

```
chmod +x ../svn.sh
../svn.sh .
cd ..
sudo dpkg-deb -b deb
```

You can then install it using:

```
sudo dpkg -i deb.deb
```

If it fails you could try to use **aptitude** instead of **apt-get**.

Comment: `wget` in `/home`? That can't work without `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type paste these commands

```
wget http://www.clshack.it/nopaste/gerix-wifi-cracker-ng-2.0-bt7.deb
sudo dpkg -i gerix-wifi-cracker-ng-2.0-bt7.deb 
sudo python /usr/share/gerix-wifi-cracker-ng/gerix.py
```

that will install and launch.

Comment: I get the error: `dpkg: error processing gerix-wifi-cracker-ng-2.0-bt7.deb (--install):
 unable to open file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci//.svn': Is a directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gerix-wifi-cracker-ng-2.0-bt7.deb`

Comment: http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/easy-way-to-fix-dpkg-svn-error/

Comment: I typed as you said and it appear an error, its need python-qt3 and i already made a question here cuz i don't know how to install python-qt3 on Ubuntu 13.10. I think is time to install 12.04