# Error installing Gerix Wifi Cracker Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I tried installing Gerix Wifi Cracker. Everything is going great until the last step where I'm supposed to install it by typing:

```
sudo dpkg -i deb.deb
```

I then get the following error message:

```
dpkg: error processing archive deb.deb (--install):
 unable to open file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci//.svn': Is a directory
```

I've only been using linux for about a week and would appreciate any kind of help!

Edit: I followed the guide that was on here [How to install Gerix-Wifi-Cracker?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379574/how-to-install-gerix-wifi-cracker)

Comment: You should read the whole guide and the comments. There is a link in the comments: https://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/easy-way-to-fix-dpkg-svn-error/

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal
2. Download your `deb` again. eg:

   ```
   cd
   wget http://www.clshack.it/nopaste/gerix-wifi-cracker-ng-2.0-bt7.deb
   ```
3. Download the package

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
   ```
4. Create a temporary folder

   ```
   mkdir ~/deb$$
   ```
5. Make a copy of the `deb` file

   ```
   cp gerix-wifi-cracker-ng-2.0-bt7.deb ~/deb$$
   ```
6. And use this commands:

   ```
   cd ~/deb$$
   dpkg-deb -x gerix-wifi-cracker-ng-2.0-bt7.deb deb
   cd deb
   dpkg-deb -e ../gerix-wifi-cracker-ng-2.0-bt7.deb
   ```
7. Create the file

   ```
   nano ../svn.sh
   ```
8. Add this code

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # SVN Emergency Fix
   function rdirls() {
       for i in $1/*
       do
           if [ -d "$i" ]
           then
             echo $i
             rm -rf $i/.svn
             rdirls $i
           else
             echo "NOT " > /dev/null 2>&1
           fi
       done
   }
   if [ -d "$1" ]
   then
     echo $1
     rm -rf ./.svn
   rdirls $1
   fi
   ```
9. Save and close
10. Use this commands

    ```
    chmod a+x ../svn.sh
    ../svn.sh .
    cd ..
    sudo dpkg-deb -b deb
    sudo dpkg -i deb.deb
    ```

<sub>[Source](https://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/easy-way-to-fix-dpkg-svn-error/)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

To install software you need to use:

```
cd directory

sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb
```

Make sure you are in the proper directory as well

Comment: Copy and paste your code and error message if that doesn't answer your question

Comment: I followed the guide that was on here http://askubuntu.com/questions/379574/how-to-install-gerix-wifi-cracker

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I follwed that guide and at the last step my error occured. I've been following that guide all along @Shane